# Questions on Formulas for expressing angles

Tags: trigonometry

I have missed some classes in precalc and trig and need some assistance figuring out how to tackle these types of problems:

It would like me to express $225^°$, $345^°$, and $195^°$ "as a sum AND as a difference of multiples of $30^°$, $45^°$ or $60^°$."

We are learning about "Formulas for $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ and the one for sine and solving for specific values.

My questions:

I can find a multiple of these numbers, but how does it relate to trig functions in general?

I assume if we find a multiple it wants us to divide the given angle by that multiple, for example $225^°/45^°= 5$ but what do I do with the 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use your knowledge of the reference angles $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, and $60^\circ$ together with the sum and difference of angle formulas 
\begin{align*}
\cos(\alpha + \beta) & = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
\cos(\alpha - \beta) & = \cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta
\end{align*}
to find the exact values of the cosine of the indicated angles.

Since $225^\circ$ is a third-quadrant angle with reference angle $45^\circ$, 
$$\cos(225^\circ) = -\cos(45^\circ) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
There is no need to use the sum or difference of angle formulas in this case.

On the other hand, if you want to find the exact value of $\cos(345^\circ)$, you can use the formula 
$$\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
by setting $\alpha = 315^\circ$ and $\beta = 30^\circ$.  Since $315^\circ$ is a fourth-quadrant angle with reference angle $45^\circ$, 
\begin{align*}
\cos(315^\circ) & = \cos(45^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\sin(315^\circ) & = -\sin(45^\circ) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}
Hence, the exact value of $\cos(345^\circ)$ is 
\begin{align*}
\cos(345^\circ) & = \cos(315^\circ + 30^\circ)\\
& = \cos(315^\circ)\cos(30^\circ) - \sin(315^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)\\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) - \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\ 
& = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align*}
You could write $345^\circ$ as a difference, as well, by setting $\alpha = 405^\circ$ and $\beta = 60^\circ$.  Since $405^\circ$ is a first-quadrant angle with reference angle $45^\circ$,
\begin{align*}
\cos(405^\circ) & = \cos(45^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\sin(405^\circ) & = \sin(45^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}
Using the formula 
$$\cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
with $\alpha = 405^\circ$ and $\beta = 60^\circ$ 
\begin{align*}
\cos(345^\circ) & = \cos(405^\circ - 60^\circ)\\
                & = \cos(405^\circ)\cos(60^\circ) + \sin(405^\circ)\sin(60^\circ)\\
& = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}}{4}
\end{align*}
which agrees with the answer we obtained using the sum of angles formula.

I will leave it to you to figure out how to find the exact value of $\cos(195^\circ)$.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the question as it is asked seems a bit weird.
Well, since 15 is the least common divisor of $30, 45$ and $60$, an angle is a sum/difference of these base values if and only if it is a multiple of $15°$. We may check that all your angles are multiples of $15°$ (divisible by 5: check, divisible by 3: also easy) so the problem indeed has a solution, yay! We may even automate the solution by noticing that $15° = 45° - 30°$, so that $n \times 15° = n \times 45° - n \times 30°$, but I suspect that this is not extremely useful except as a joke answer. For example this gives $225° = 15 \times 15° = 15 \times 45° - 15 \times 30°$.

Now an indication of an actual, serious solution :-)
For the $345°$ angle, this is really close to $360°$ = one full turn, so we may rewrite it in a simpler way as $360° - $ something. I leave the details to you!
This suggests that the question was to be understood as: “multiples of 180° ± one of 30°, 45° or 60°”. This means that for each of your angles, you should look for the closest multiple of 180° (= integer number of half-turns) and consider the difference. Why $180°$? Because these relations are obviously meant to be used for computing sines and cosines, and $\sin (180° + x)$ is really really easy to compute.

For example, for a 135° angle, the closest multiple is 180°, and the difference is $180° - 135° = 45°$, so that the answer would be $135° = 180° - 45°$. I leave the three answers to you (the last one is a bit more tricky, you will have to use the $15° = 45° - 30°$ relation I quoted earlier!).